# Use Predicate as a Argument for Unit Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, predicate

I currently have a function that uses the data type predicate as one of the parameters for the function. See below:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET)
function getAll(WebRequest request, @QuerydslPredicate(root = Image.class) Predicate predicate, @PageableDefault Pageable pageable) {
   return "test"
}
```

However, I am currently writing Unit test to test the validity of this function, and I'm having a hard time trying to pass a argument for the Predicate into this function so I can test. Can someone please assist?? This is the test function I have so far:

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class ImageTest {

 private Predicate predicate;

 @InjectMocks
ImageController imageController = new ImageController(); 

 @Test
public void testGetAll() throws Exception {
    WebRequest webRequest = mock(WebRequest.class);

    ResponseEntity responseEntity = ok(new PagedResponse<>(page));
    when(imageController.getAll(Mockito.eq(webRequest), Mockito.eq(predicate), any(Pageable.class)))
            .thenReturn(responseEntity);
   }
}
```

In this instance, predicate is null because I'm not sure what to set as the argument

Comment: Can you show us the code you have setup to test at the moment?

Comment: @Adam yes! I have updated my description above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `any(Pageable.class)` as last argument.

You need to use `Mockito.eq()` for other two arguments:

```
when(imageController.getAll(Mockito.eq(webRequest), Mockito.eq(predicate), any(Pageable.class)))
  .thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Comment: thank you! I seem to be getting a null pointer exception however after making this change; further it says "Misplaced or misused argument matcher"; does that have something to do with my imageController class?

Comment: try to show all the entire test class.. or as much as possible

Comment: how you instantiate predicate and how declare instantiate the controller?

Comment: Please see the new additions above. I have included everything from my current test class

Comment: Based on your code you can easily any everywhere: any(webRequest.class), any(Predicate.class), any(Pageable.class))

Comment: Hmm.. I'm still receiving an error after changes. "You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing."

Comment: Add @Spy on ImageController and use doReturn instead of when

Comment: Thank you the test has passed!